# Script to create folders in multiple directories using YYYYMMDD date as the folder name

Tags: windows, batch, file-management

At work every morning I have to create multiple file folders (using a `YYYYMMDD` date format as the file folder name) in different directories across our network for various departments. This is a real pain and time waster, and I would like to automate the process. So my question is:

Does anyone know how I can write a script that uses the current system date in `YYYYMMDD` format, and creates multiple folders in different network directories with each folder named as the date in `YYYYMMDD` format?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: pet peeve: the Windows command prompt is not DOS. DOS is a 16-bit operating system that is mostly dead. I re-tagged the question to reflect that.

Comment: A pilot is flying a plane and is lost in fog. He is low on fuel and his passengers are nervous. At last he sees a tall building with one guy working on the 5th floor. The pilot banks and shouts through his open window: "Hey, where am I?". The office worker replies: "You're in an airplane.". 

The answer the guy in the building gave the pilot was 100% correct but absolutely useless. While you are absolutely right that command prompt is not DOS, it is what most people understand. 

My 2 cents: we should focus on making things accessible/searcheable - even if they are not 100% correctly labeled.

Comment: @Vinayak If you actually had a question about DOS, would you enjoy sifting through topics that were 95% about Windows?

Answer (score 9):

Create a batch file that looks like this:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%i in ('date /t') do set yyyymmdd=%%k%%j%%i
echo Date: %yyyymmdd%

mkdir \\server1\share1\subdir1\%yyyymmdd%
mkdir \\server1\share2\subdir2\%yyyymmdd%
mkdir \\server2\share3\subdir3\%yyyymmdd%
...
```

**Warning**: the format of the date (*yyyymmdd=%%k%%j%%i*) depends on your regional settings. Because I use the French date format (dd/mm/yyyy), I have to use "*%%k%%j%%i*" as the format (%%i = day, %%j = month, %%j = year).

If your regional settings are set to US style (mm/dd/yyyy), you should use "*%%k%%i%%j*" (%%i = month, %%j = day, %%j = year).

---

If you want to include the time as well, use this:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%i in ('date /t') do set yyyymmdd=%%k%%j%%i
echo Date: %yyyymmdd%
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=: " %%i in ('echo %time%') do set hhmmss=%%i%%j%%k
echo Time: %hhmmss%

mkdir \\server1\share1\subdir1\%yyyymmdd%%hhmmss%
```

The date is stored in the variable `%yyyymmdd%`, the time in `%hhmmss%` .
Same remark as above for the date, not applicable for the time.

You could use a separator between the date and time: `%yyyymmdd%_%hhmmss%` for instance.

Comment: could you show an example including time as well?

Comment: @marked: updated my answer with an example including time

Answer (score 0):

Another, uglier but much more flexible way, is to generate a separate batch file for every directory that needs to be created, that (a) creates the directory and (b) renames the next batch file that needs to be executed to a previously selected common name. You just run a batch file with that common name every day

Answer (score 0):

Try these options:

```
set name=%date%
set name2=%name:~6,4%-%name:~3,2%-%name:~0,2%
set tm=%time%
set name3=%tm:~0,2%-%tm:~3,2%
set finname=%name2%_%name3%
mkdir \\Server\Share1\Subfolder1\%finname%
```

Comment: In case I want to do the same for all working days in the month (e.g. say for month of May 2018, i want to create all the folders for 01st May, then 02nd May and so on and so forth - 20180501, 20180502, 20180503....). then how do i iterate it ?, any suggestions are welcome.