# Windows command-line: create a file with the current date in its name

Tags: windows, bash, environment-variables

I'm trying to create a zip file from a batch script.
I need it to be named like archive_.zip

Unfortunately, this doesn't work on systems with the date formatted like y/m/d because of the slashes:

```
zip some_options "archive_%DATE%.zip"
```

The `%DATE%` variable expands to something like

```
Mon 09/28/2009
```

I have access to the gnuwin32 package, so I could use, say, `sed` to replace spaces and slashes by dashes. The problem is, how would I use the output of `sed` to create the file name of the zip archive?

In Unix (bash), one can use back-quotes to evaluate-in-place a command and use its output in another command, something like:

```
zip [...] archive_`echo %DATE% | sed -e s/.../.../`.zip
```

Is there anything similar available in Windows?

Or maybe there's a way to set a variable to the returned value of `sed` and use that to construct the file name?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can replace symbols in variables by using :

```
set _date=%DATE:/=-%
```

Comment: This is a neat trick!

Comment: P.S. Is there a 'one-liner' way to get rid of spaces or other nasty characters too? (as opposed to having a 3rd...nth temp variable for each character to replace)

Comment: No sorry. There seems to be no such thing. You have to fallback to the for syntax to do that. NB: This is a nice reference for batch-programming : http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchfiles.php

Comment: this is even faster than: `%date:~-10,2%-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-4,4%`  !

Comment: How has no one +1 your response Jess Stone!  +1 from me!!!

Comment: You can remove a space in a variable using `%date: =%` (space on the left, nothing on the right)

Comment: @JessStone I do prefer your style (thus the +1) but it assumes the system DATE format (for this user) is "Ddd YYYY/MM/DD"  and makes the result "DDMMYYYY" but what if the system's DATE format is: "Ddd MM/DD/YYYY" then it becomes "MYYYDDMM" and cause no end of confusion. So I prefer to test several common formats, like this: `if "%DATE:~6,1%"=="/" set D=%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%` and similar for other formats.

Answer (score 7):

I have posted an answer to a very similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/39377/script-to-create-folders-in-multiple-directories-using-yyyymmdd-date-as-the-folde/39464#39464). The spltting of the date in fields is done in 1 line, instead of several lines in harrymc's answer.

The interesting part is:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%i in ('date /t') do set yyyymmdd=%%k%%j%%i
echo Date: %yyyymmdd%
```

And the warning is still relevant:

> **Warning**: the format of the date
>   (yyyymmdd=%%k%%j%%i) depends on your
>   regional settings. Because I use the
>   French date format (dd/mm/yyyy), I
>   have to use "%%k%%j%%i" as the format
>   (%%i = day, %%j = month, %%j = year).
>
> If your regional settings are set to
>   US style (mm/dd/yyyy), you should use
>   "%%k%%i%%j" (%%i = month, %%j = day,
>   %%j = year).

Answer (score 5):

I always use:

```
For /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5 delims=/. " %%a in ('date/T') do set CDate=%%a%%b%%c%%d
```

Then CDate will be Sat02182012. If you want to make it more sortable set CDate to %%d-%%b-%%c so it will be 2012-02-18

```
For /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%f in ('time /t') do set CTime=%%f%%g
```

To make date and time folder/file friendly.

Answer (score 3):

This rather horrid bit of code should do something like what you want

```
move "Filename.txt" "Filename%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%_%Time:~0,2%%Time:~3,2%%Time:~6,2%.txt"
```

If you change the filename appropriately.

Comment: Care to explain the monstrosity? :)

Comment: It's basically chopping bits out of the date and feeding it to the middle of the filename, you can test it by doing echo then parts of the horror at the command line so if you do echo %date:~6,4% it gives the year. It's just substringing the date and time.

Comment: Interesting. Not too portable unfortunately...

Comment: Unfortunately the problem with using substrings is that it relies on a certain date format, and blows up when it's different. `echo %date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%` returns `9-289-20` on my machine since I have the date set to use yyyy-MM-dd (so today is 2009-09-28).

Comment: True, I only use this solution on one machine so it's not too much of an issue.

Answer (score 3):

Since your question is tagged as Windows, I found this solution that works in the good old .bat files : 
["Windows Batch File (.bat) to get current date in MMDDYYYY format"](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/956/windows-batch-file-bat-to-get-current-date-in-mmddyyyy-format/),
 and can probably be adapted to your case:

> echo on
> @REM Seamonkey’s quick date batch (MMDDYYYY format)
> @REM Setups %date variable
> @REM First parses month, day, and year into mm , dd, yyyy formats and then combines to be MMDDYYYY
>
> FOR /F “TOKENS=1* DELIMS= ” %%A IN (’DATE/T’) DO SET CDATE=%%B
> FOR /F “TOKENS=1,2 eol=/ DELIMS=/ ” %%A IN (’DATE/T’) DO SET mm=%%B
> FOR /F “TOKENS=1,2 DELIMS=/ eol=/” %%A IN (’echo %CDATE%’) DO SET dd=%%B
> FOR /F “TOKENS=2,3 DELIMS=/ ” %%A IN (’echo %CDATE%’) DO SET yyyy=%%Bv
> vSET date=%mm%%dd%%yyyy%

this does nothing but setup the %date variable to be todays date in MMDDYYYY format so it can be called later in the script.

**Edit**
Found a better syntax. Given that my date is today "Mon 28/09/2009":
set day=%Date:~0,2%
set month=%Date:~7,2%
set year=%Date:~10,4%

Answer (score 3):

```
zip some_options "archive_%date:/=-%.zip"
```

the `/=-` substitutes the `/` with a minus sign.

Answer (score 2):

pure cmd.exe version in combination with the gnuwin32-'date':

```
%> for /F "usebackq" %d in ( `date.exe +"%y%m%d"` ) do zip archive_%d.zip <folder>
```

Comment: So it *can* do in-place substitutions! If you ask me, the 'for' command has one weird syntax...

Comment: i didnt claim it could not :) the whole 'cmd' stuff is crazy anyway, whoever designed that was deep into some kind of bad dream.

the 'for' cmd actually creates lines (aka 'unrolls' the 'loop') in the first pass and then executes the so 'created' script.

Answer (score 1):

what about using cscript + vbasic:

```
WScript.shell.run "zip archive_" & DatePart("yyyy", Now) & "_" & DatePart("m", Now) & "_" & DatePart("d", Now) & ".zip " & WScript.arguments(0)
```

call it via

```
cscript /nologo zip_it.vbs
```

Answer (score 1):

For /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5 delims=/. " %%a in ('date/T') do set CDate=%%d-%%b-%%c

@echo data = %CDate%

This is in the Year-Month-Day that is most common now days

Answer (score 1):

Any solution that uses either `%DATE%` or the output of `date /t` is likely to break if the user has modified his/her regional settings.  For example, I've set my "short date" format to `"yyyy-MM-dd"`, so I have `%DATE%` equal to `"2012-02-18"`, and `date /t` produces the same output.  (This is for Windows 7; I presume it's the same for earlier versions of Windows.)

Build a batch file and then execute it.

Since you have the GNU `date` command available, you can do something like this:

```
C:\path\to\gnu\date "+zip some_options archive_%Y-%m-%d.zip" > tmp.bat
call .\tmp.bat
```

`tmp.bat` will contain something like:

```
zip some_options archive_2012-02-18.zip
```

Note that this creates `tmp.bat` in the current directory, which might be a problem; it might be better to create `%TEMP%\tmp.bat`.  I also didn't remove the file afterward; that's easy enough to do.

`date +FORMAT` lets you specify the output format of the `date` command, similar to a `printf` format string; see [the coreutils date documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/date-invocation.html) for details.  The format can include arbitrary text, so in this case you don't even need to use `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, if you put everyone's bits together you get something that works for you.
This is on a Windows 2003 system to give me a snapshot of running processes in response to a trigger from the performance monitor:

```
@echo off
For /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5 delims=/. " %%i in ('date /t') do set CDate=%%k%%j%%i
For /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%f in ('time /t') do set CTime=%%f%%g
tasklist /fo table >tasklist%CDate%%CTime%.txt
```

The output file is named in one string with no delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

```
zip [...] archive_`echo %DATE% | tr / -`.zip
```

Should work.

On the other hand - perhaps you have `date` command available (I don't know Windows). If yes, then just do:

```
zip [...] archive_`date +'%Y-%m-%d'`.zip
```

Comment: The backtick trick doesn't work in cmd.exe. And the Windows 'date' command can't handle formatting :(

Answer (score 0):

`%date%` and `date /t` command don’t work. I have different regional settings in different accounts and the following is output in them:

first account:

```
>echo %date%
03.04.2021
```

second account:

```
>echo %date%
Sat 04/03/2021
```

The solution that will probably suite me is:

```
REM file getCurrentDateFormatted.vbs

Function Rpad(strInput, length, character)
  Rpad = Right(String(length, character) & strInput, length)
end function

ts = Now()
WScript.StdOut.Write Year(ts) & "_" & Rpad(Month(ts), 2, "0") & "_" & Rpad(Day(ts), 2, "0")
```

> Yes, there's no `Rpad` function in CSCRIPT :(

How to use:

```
>CSCRIPT /Nologo getCurrentDateFormatted.vbs
2021_04_03
```

Answer (score -1):

not sure if it suits you, but my code is

```
@ECHO OFF
set ldt=%date% %time%
echo %ldt%>> logs.txt
```

Comment: The OP wants a file with the current date in the *file name*, not in the *file contents*